# Black spot on mmd model's face

Tags: modeling

Is there any software I can install so I can fix this? I should've added this when I asked on Reddit. All the tutorials either use the wrong version of blender or are outdated. I am pretty new to Blender and technology is very frustrating to me.

Comment: You don't say a lot, if you've imported a 3D model from another software, you may have black artefacts, you can fix this going into Properties panel > Object Data > Ggeometry Data > Clear Custom Split Normals Data

Comment: Add a screenshot or . blend file.